# mysql/paypal - How to deal with the user paying half or full fees?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

So I have the following problem. I have two tables:

```
paypal_log
user_fees
```

The fee is fixed, 9000. But I also want to let the user be able to pay for half, 4500, and then 4500 will remain to pay later. I am using paypal to do the payment. When the data is posted to paypal, the `paypal_log` table also gets populated with the data.

The user completes the payment on paypal, and paypal sends an ipn, which then I use to get transaction id, `payment_status` and update the `paypal_log` table. Then I need to update the `user_fees` table.

Here, what I do is, I have a column in the `paypal_log` table called isHalf. The query checks if the amount is 4500 and isHalf = 0, then it updates user_fees from 9000, to 4500 and updates is isHalf to 1.

Then there's another if statement, that checks if amount is 4500 and isHalf is 1, at which point it updates user_fees to 0.00.

The first check is for 9000, which automatically goes to 0.00 and it's simple. The problems appear when the user starts a payment and cancels it or starts a payment and just goes off the page because a record still gets created.

My check is below:

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid FROM paypal_log WHERE invoice_id = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt1->bind_param('i', $invoice_id); //invoice ID that Paypal sent back
        $stmt1->execute();
        $stmt1->store_result();
        $stmt1->bind_result($db_userid);
        $stmt1->fetch();
        $stmt1->close();

    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT isHalf, product_amount FROM paypal_log WHERE userid = ? ORDER BY created_on ASC LIMIT 1");
    $stmt1->bind_param('i', $db_userid);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();
    $stmt1->bind_result($isHalf, $product_amount);
    $stmt1->fetch();
    $stmt1->close();

    if ($product_amount == '9000.00' ) {

    $full_fees = 0.00;
    $updated_on = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");

    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user_fees SET fee_amount=?, updated_on=? WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt2->bind_param('isi', $full_fees, $updated_on, $db_userid);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->close();

    } else {

    if ($product_amount == '4500.00' AND $isHalf == '0' ) {

    $half_fees = 4500.00;
    $isHalf = 1;
    $updated_on = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");

    $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user_fees SET fee_amount=?, updated_on=? WHERE userid=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt3->bind_param('isi', $half_fees, $updated_on, $db_userid);
    $stmt3->execute();
    $stmt3->close();

    $stmt4 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE paypal_log SET isHalf=?, updated_on=? WHERE userid=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt4->bind_param('isi', $isHalf, $updated_on, $db_userid);
    $stmt4->execute();
    $stmt4->close();

} else {

    $full_fees = 0.00;
    $updated_on = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");

    $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user_fees SET fee_amount=?, updated_on=? WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt5->bind_param('isi', $full_fees, $updated_on, $db_userid);
    $stmt5->execute();
    $stmt5->close();
}
}
```

I tried to explain it as straight forward as possible. I am aware that my logic is probably not right, hence why I thought I might receive some good answers that will make me think.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to rethink your data model. As a start, every time a payment is made you should probably be doing an INSERT into a payments table on your end to record this payment. Then if you want or need to have an account status (fully paid, partially paid) make it a derived status on a different database entity (such as an account record), which you could in theory regenerate from your payments table. This allows you to decouple your logic from PayPal api & ipn handling.

Comment: Also: it is unclear from your question when you are writing to a db; if you are writing only upon IPN receipt your db statuses should not change from someone visiting a page. Posting the code above doesn't explain this since when this code is executed is not clear.

Comment: I write to the database twice. Once when the user clicks the Pay button. And the second time, when I receive the ipn.